# How to join Kafka KStream to Kstream of 3 Topics

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 3 Topics : "BEGIN", "CONTINUE" and "END"
These three topic needs to be joined in one Topic Message where i can get the Result Model that is a combination of the 3 Topic Messages.

There are many example that shows how to join 2 topics.
If anyone can give me an example or a hint of how can i make a Join or these 3 Topics.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you try to achieve. Do all messages have an ID you want to use for the join? Will there be exactly one message per topic that should be joined, or could it be multiple (ie, from the CONTINUE) topic? What is the time-relationship between those events?

Answer (score 2):

Until the [cogroup feature](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-150+-+Kafka-Streams+Cogroup) gets implemented, you will need to first merge your first 2 topics into an intermediary topic, and then join that one with your 3rd topic.

For an example of how to do that, see [the cogroup KIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-150+-+Kafka-Streams+Cogroup).

Answer (score 0):

I depends on what kind of join you want to do. As you say, you have `KStream`, you would do two consecutive windowed joins:

```java
KStream stream1 = builder.stream(...);
KStream stream2 = builder.stream(...);
KStream stream3 = builder.stream(...);

KStream joined = stream1.join(stream2, ...)
                        .join(stream3, ...);
```